# Using asset_path in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

In my `Character` model I have added:

**character.rb**

```
before_save do
  self.profile_picture_url = asset_path('icon.png')
end
```

However, for all the Characters that already exist in the database, their `profile_picture_url` is `nil`. I therefore want to enter the console and iterate through all of them and set it. In the console I tried:

```
Character.find_each do |c|
  c.profile_picture_url = asset_path('icon.png')
end
```

But this gives the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `asset_path' for main:Object
```

I hope I have adequately communicated what I am trying to achieve. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 21):

Check out the documentation for [AssetHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html):

> This module provides methods for generating asset paths and urls.

You can access `asset_path` in the console a few ways:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('icon.png')
```

*Or*

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper
asset_path('icon.png')
```

Also on a side note and separate from the question, *if* you are updating all of your `Character`'s I would use [update_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) for your `profile_picture_url` attribute.

```
Character.update_all(profile_picture_url: asset_path('icon.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to call `asset_path`, other than helpers or views, then call like

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("icon.png")
```